Well defined notion of the tangent space to the preimage of a constant through a?
Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces and $L: X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear map, $c \in Y$.
I'm looking for a rigorous definition of "the tangent space to $L^{-1}(c)$", denoted $\mathcal{T}L^{-1}(c)$, one which would also make it relatively easy to identify $\mathcal{T}L^{-1}(c)$ with $\ker L$, as I've seen done in some places without any explanation.
I'm thinking that one route to go would be seeing $X,Y$ as Banach manifolds, but that seems overly complicated. If this is the only way, then how would this identification go in the context of Banach manifolds?

You mean the tangent space at an arbitrary point $x\in L^{-1}(c)$. Of course, as with any affine linear subspace, the vector space in question is independent of $x$.

@TedShifrin My question is for a framework as simple as possible in which the tangent space to that affine linear subspace is defined rigorously, in a way that it is also the object on which differentials of differentiable functions between Banach spaces are defined.
